# Sorting before doing GROUP BY in MongoDB

Tags: mongodb, aggregation-framework, database

I have a mongo database for bug tracking. It contains 2 collections:

**Project**

```
{
    "_id": 1,
    "name": "My Project"
}
```

**Bug**

```
{
    "_id": 1,
    "project": 1,
    "title": "we have a bug",
    "timestamp": 1400215183000
}
```

On the dashboard, I want to display the latest bug of each project - up to total of 10.
So basically, when doing **GROUP BY** `"project"` field, I need to make sure it will always select the LATEST bug (by doing a pre-sort by `"timestamp"`).

I'm not sure how to combine sorting and grouping together, thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In order to get the "lastest" bug per project while limiting to 10 results:

```js
db.collection.aggregate({
    { "$sort": { "timestamp": -1, "project": 1 } },
    { "$group": {
        "_id": "$project",
        "bug": {
            "$first": {
                "_id": "$_id",
                "title": "$title",
                "timestamp": "$timestamp"
            }
        }
    }},
    { "$limit": 10 }
})
```

So the sorting is done by timestamp and project (as an optimization) then you do the [**`$group`**](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/group/) and the [**`$limit`**](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/limit/). The grouping here is just looking on the "boundaries" using [**`$first`**](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/first/), and just returning all of the rest of the document, which you may or may not need.

Try to actually restrict your "timestamp" range using [**`$match`**](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/match/) first in order to optimize this.